# Quicksort Algorithm throws StackOverflowException

Tags: java, algorithm

For a homework assignment, I have to write an implementation of the QuickSort algorithm and use this to sort a list with 100k numbers in some random order.

In the first part of the assignment, I have to use the first item of the array as the pivot element. This indeed returns a sorted list. However, for the second part of the assignment I have to use the last item as the pivot, which results in a StackOverflowException. When I try it in a smaller collection of 8 records, it DOES work correctly. I've been looking at my code but I can't figure out where I'm making a mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
public class QuickSort {

    private QuickSortStrategyEnum quickSortStrategy;

    public QuickSort(QuickSortStrategyEnum quickSortStrategy) {

        this.quickSortStrategy = quickSortStrategy;
    }

    public List<Integer> sortIntegerArray(List<Integer> arrayList, int left, int right) {

        if ( left >= right ) {
            return arrayList;
        }

        int i = partition(arrayList, left, right);

        if (i <= right) {

            int pivotNew = partition(arrayList, i, right);
            int pivotIndex = arrayList.indexOf(pivotNew);

            arrayList = sortIntegerArray(arrayList, left , pivotIndex - 1);
            arrayList = sortIntegerArray(arrayList, pivotIndex + 1, right);
        }

        return arrayList;
    }

    private int partition(List<Integer> arrayList, int left, int right) {

        int pivot = getPivot(arrayList, left, right);
        int i = left + 1;

        for (int j = i; j <= right; j++) {

            if (arrayList.get(j) < pivot) {

                Collections.swap(arrayList, j, i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        Collections.swap(arrayList, left, i - 1);
        return i;
    }

    private int getPivot(List<Integer> arrayList, int left, int right) {

        int pivot = 0;

        switch (quickSortStrategy) {

            case FIRST:
            pivot = arrayList.get(left);
            break;

            case LAST:
            pivot = arrayList.get(right);
            break;
        }
        return pivot;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would help to know what method/line throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the fact that David Harkness pointed out, there are problems with the partition logic. Try this out: (after removing things pointed by David Harkness)

```
private int partition(List<Integer> arrayList, int left, int right) {

    int pivot = getPivot(arrayList, left, right);
    int i = left - 1; 

    for (int j = left; j < right; j++) {
        if (arrayList.get(j) <= pivot) {
            i++;
            Collections.swap(arrayList, j, i);
        }
    }

    Collections.swap(arrayList, i+1, right);
    return i+1;
}
```

It will work for case when pivot is last element. Not for First element.

**Read, understand the working on paper, dry run things out, write pseudo code and then say hello to Eclipse.** Dont hurry to implement things.

Comment: If left is the first element (0), you make the index `i` -1, which causes `Collections.swap(arrayList, j, i);` to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. In Sander's code, the line is `int i = left + 1;`. Is this a copy-paste error?

Comment: Aaah you're right :) I dove into trying to program a solution too soon, before actually understanding the process. Now I understand how it works and can continue with this solution. I can't upvote you unfortunately as I haven't got enough points but thanks a lot!

Comment: @JessevanAssen Observe that before calling Collections.swap (arrayList, j, i), I incremented i. I have tested my code and it works

Answer (score 5):

Hint: What can happen if `right == left + 1`?

Comment: +1 stepping through the code in a debugger would be useful. ;)

Comment: Beyond `partition` doing a bunch of busy-work, I don't see a problem with this condition. I'm only stepping through it in my head, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

These two lines look fishy:

```
int pivotNew = partition(arrayList, i, right);
int pivotIndex = arrayList.indexOf(pivotNew);
```

Look at what `partition` returns and compare it to how you use its result.

Comment: Hmm you're right here, fixed this now. :) Unfortunately I haven't got enough points yet to upvote you..